# Can't get InvocationList from DataContextChanged

Tags: .net, wpf, delegates

Why second line with `GetInvocationList()` not compiling ?
`DataContextChanged` event declared same as `MyDataContextChanged`.

```
public partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public event DependencyPropertyChangedEventHandler MyDataContextChanged;

    public TestControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var invocationList = MyDataContextChanged.GetInvocationList();
        //var invocationList = DataContextChanged.GetInvocationList(); NotWorking
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `public event` is translated by the compiler into a `private` delegate backing field and `public` `add` and `remove` methods.

So from outside the declaring class, you can only use the `event` to add or remove handlers (via `+=` and `-=` operators). But you cannot access the backing field.

To call `GetInvocationList()` you need access to the delegate field, but this is `private`.

So you *can* call `GetInvocationList()` for your own `MyDataContextChanged`, because its backing field is `private` in your own `TestControl` class.

The backing field for the `DataContextChanged` event is `private` in a base class of `TestControl` (not sure if `UserControl` or further up the hierarchy). So you don't have access from within your derived `TestControl` class.